# Unity C# TMP Input Field onChange issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a game in Unity with C# and just ran into an issue that i can't figure a solution on. I am doing an Curency Exchange system in-real mode, so how it is supposed to work, is that i currently have 2 currencies, CTC and USD. When i type for example "2" in CTC, it should then exchange 2 CTC to USD and then type that output value into the USD input field, and same goes other way. This is meant for the player to be able to convert both from usd to ctc, and from ctc to usd, in a easy and simplified way.

Here is my current code:

```
void Start() {
        ClientSellorBuyCTCInput.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { SellBuyUSDChange(); });
        ClientSellorBuyUSDInput.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { SellBuyCTCChange(); });
}

public void SellBuyUSDChange()
    {
        string CTCTXT = ClientSellorBuyCTCInput.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        double CTCToUSD = Convert.ToDouble(CTCTXT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / CTCValue;
        Debug.Log(CTCTXT + " CTC is worth " + CTCToUSD + " USD");
        ClientSellorBuyUSDInput.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = CTCToUSD.ToString();
    }

    public void SellBuyCTCChange()
    {
        string USDTXT = ClientSellorBuyUSDInput.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        double USDtoCTC = CTCValue * Convert.ToDouble(USDTXT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Debug.Log(USDTXT + " USD is worth " + USDtoCTC + " CTC");
        ClientSellorBuyCTCInput.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = USDtoCTC.ToString();
    }
```

My only guess for this to a solution is to detect what input field that is activated when a player types in it, and make sure that if the other one isn't activated, it wont interfere with the other one as a loop as it currently are doing. But i'd need some help to figure out how (i am kinda new to Unity, never really finished a complete game, and never dealt with this input stuff before).

I hope you understand my typings, and spellings as i am very noob to English.

Thanks for any idea and recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
ClientSellorBuyCTCInput.onValueChanged.AddListener(SellBuyUSDChange);
public void SellBuyUSDChange(string data)
{
    Debug.Log(data);
    ...
}
```

I hope it will work for you.